# div not showing up in firefox

Tags: php, html, css

i am developing a web application,I have made some div which is visible in each browser.one of my div is not showing up on firefox.What are the possible reasons.

here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uZd3u/1/)

i have given the `background-color:black` to the div which is not showing up.

**css**

```
html, body
{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#main_header
{
    height:20%;
    border-bottom:3px solid grey;
}
#user_info
{
    height:40%;
    width:auto;
    float:right;
    text-align:right;
    position:relative;
    right:3%;
    top:42%;
}
#user_info span
{
    font-size:1.2em;
    font-weight:600;
}
#logo
{
    height:60%;
    width:25%;
    float:left;
    background-image:url('../images/ibuildmart_logo.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    position:relative;
    left:5%;
    top:20%;
}

#main_wrapper
{
    height:75%;
}
#menu_wrap
{
    width:10%;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    background-color:yellow;
}
#content_wrap
{
    width:90%%;
    height:100%;
    float:right ;
}
#content
{   
    background-color:black;
    width:95%;
    height:92%;
    border-radius:20px;
    -moz-border-radius:20px;
    margin:2%;
    overflow:auto;
}
#main_footer
{
    height:5%;
    background-color:blue;;
}
```

**html**

```
 <div id="main_header">
  <?php
include_once('header.php');
?>
</div>


<div id="main_wrapper">
  <div id="menu_wrap">
  </div>
  <div id="content_wrap">
    <div id="content">

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<div id="main_footer">

  <?php
include_once('footer.php');
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Which `div` is not showing up on Firefox? You may want to check your fiddle - you are ending your comments with `--!>` rather than `-->`, which will not work.

Comment: ok but how come this is working in another browser>?I have updated fiddle

Comment: Chrome seems to accept `--!>` as an ending comment. It doesn't work on Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firs thing is the HTML comments are not closed properly. And the main reason is you are using double `%` in ID `content_wrap`.

Here is the ***[Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/uZd3u/5/)***

```
#content_wrap
{
    width:90%%; /*you are using double percentage here*/
    height:100%;
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: Eagle eyes, @kheema pandey

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple problems:

http://jsfiddle.net/uZd3u/2/

You closed your HTML comments with `--!>` which is wrong. It have to be like this: `<!-- comment -->`

Your `content_wrap` was `float: right;`

Comment: ok but how come this is working in another browser>?I have updated fiddle

Comment: Look at @Kheema Pandey he saw you used double percentage.